# Stuck with separating of the several loops in python

Tags: python, loops, cycle

So, I’m stuck with separating the multiple loops.
The first cycle works fine. And the second one too. But not the two last ones. When I’m trying to type the DNA or Protein, it only gives an answer: Restart? Y \ N

My code:

```
while True:
 A = (input())
 if A == ("Start"):
  print ("What type of the data you want to process?")
  print ("DNA", "RNA", "Protein", sep="\n")
  break
 else:
  print ("Incorrect input")
  continue
  break

while True:
 X = (input())
 if X == ("RNA"):
  print ("What you want to do with RNA?", "RNA to DNA?  RNA to Protein? seqRNA length?", sep="\n?")
  continue
  break
 else:
  print("Restart?", "Y \ N", sep="\n")
  continue
  break

while True:
 Y = (input())
 if Y == ("DNA"):
  print ("What you want to do with DNA?", "DNA to RNA? seqDNA length?", sep="\n")
  continue
  break
 else:
  print("Anything else?", "Yes No", sep="\n")
  continue
  break

while True:
 Z = (input())
 if Z == ("Protein"):
  print ("What you want to do with Protein?", "Protein to RNA? protein Name?", sep="\n")
  continue
  break
 else:
  print("Anything else?", "Yes No", sep="\n")
  continue
  break
```

I’m already tried to delete one of these cycles and tried to run it, but the results were the same. I had searched for the examples of using break, while and if, but found answers only for just the only one loop, not multiple. I find it quite dissapointing, because I’ve wanted to do this for a better understanding of the python. And not just using a BioPython library.  But ironically, just the process of the transcription, reverse transcription, translation, translation to RNA, or sequence length calculation is not a big problem. It’s all needs just a one line of the code.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to remove `continue`?

Comment: I've tried to remove it and add by the different ways, most of  this combinations I can't remember. But it's doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:

    print("What type of the data you want to process?", "RNA? DNA?", sep = "\n")
    A = input("")
    if A == "RNA":
          print("What you want to do with RNA?", "(a1)RNA to Protein? (a2)RNA to DNA? (a3)RNA Length? (a4)RNA Splicing? (a5)RNA nucleotides (a6)ratio? RNAi? ", sep = "\n")
          break

    if A == "DNA":
          print("What you want to do with DNA", "(b1)DNA to RNA? (b2)DNA length? (b3)DNA nucleotides ratio? (b4)Complimentary DNA chain?", sep = "\n")
          break



    else:
         print("Nope") #TF2 references
         continue


while A == "RNA":
    X = input("")
    if X == "a1":
     print("Input RNA")
     import ptranslation #Written by myself module for RNA translation
     RNA_translation = input("")
     print (RNA_translation)
     break
    if X == "a2":
     print("Input RNA")
     RNA_seq = input("")
     DNA_seq  = RNA_seq.replace("U", "T")
     print (DNA_seq)
     break
    if X == "a3":
     print ("Input RNA")
     RNA = input("")
     RNAo = int (len(RNA)//2)
     print(RNAo)
     break
    if X == "a4":
     print ("Input RNA")
     import re
     RNA = input("")
     regex = r"GU(?:\w{0,}?)AG" #regex black magic Uga-Buga, still need to undestand it better
     exons = re.sub(regex, '', RNA)
     print(exons)
     break
    if X == ("a5"):
     print("Input RNA")
     RNAn = input ("")
     X = (RNAn.count("A")) + (RNAn.count("U")) + (RNAn.count("C")) + (RNAn.count ("G"))
     A = (RNAn.count("A")/X)
     U = (RNAn.count("U")/X)
     G = (RNAn.count("G")/X)
     C = (RNAn.count("C")/X)
     print ("A =", A, "U =", U, "G =", G, "C =", C)
     break
    if X == ("a6"):
        print("Input RNA")
        N = input("")
        print(N.translate(str.maketrans({"A": "U", "G": "C", "U": "A", "C": "G"})))
        break
    else:
      print("NOPE! Input correct option!")
      continue
      break

while A == "DNA":
    Y = input("")
    if Y == "b1":
     print ("Input DNA ")
     DNA_seq = input("")
     RNA_seq  = DNA_seq.replace("T", "U")
     print (RNA_seq)
     break
    if Y == ("b2"):
        print("Input DNA")
        DNA = input("")
        DNAo = int (len(DNA)//2)
        print(DNAo)
        break
    if Y == ("b3"):
        print("Input DNA")
        DNAn = input ("")
        X = (DNAn.count("A")) + (DNAn.count("T")) + (DNAn.count("C")) + (DNAn.count ("G"))
        A = (DNAn.count("A")/X)
        T = (DNAn.count("T")/X)
        G = (DNAn.count("G")/X)
        C = (DNAn.count("C")/X)
        print ("A =", A, "T =", T, "G =", G, "C =", C)
        break
    if Y == ("b4"):
        print("Input DNA")
        Nd = input("")
        print(Nd.translate(str.maketrans({"A": "T", "G": "C", "T": "A", "C": "G"})))
        break
    else:
      print("NOPE! Input correct option!")
      continue
      break
#psyhological support in process of  the coding - M.Kashtanov
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve cleaned up and restructured your code a bit. Is this what you wanted?

```
while True:

    print("What type of the data you want to process?")
    A = input("DNA, RNA, Protein > ")
    if A == "DNA":
        print("What you want to do with DNA?")
        Y = input("DNA to RNA? seqDNA length? > ")
        # Test and do something with Y

    elif A == "RNA":
        print("What you want to do with RNA?")
        X = input("RNA to DNA?  RNA to Protein? seqRNA length? > ")
        # Test and do something with X

    elif A == "Protein":
        print("What you want to do with Protein?")
        Z = input("Protein to RNA? protein Name? > ")
        # Test and do something with Z

    else:
        print("Incorrect input")
        continue

    # If user wants to restart, stay in the loop, else break.
    if input("Restart? Y \ N > ") == "N":
        break
```

Comment: You even added a restart option.   Will try to learn more from your answer and create a lesser crappy code for a next time. And again, many thanks!

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist You’re welcome. I’ve always found it helpful to learn from other people’s code — assuming it was well-written. Coding is a minimalist endeavor: the simpler the better. If your code looks/feels messy then retry, it can likely be improved. Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the continue statements once you get passed the Start condition and rna/dna/protein condition.

I only tested for RNA but I removed the continue statement after the print and it seemed to work

what is your intention with the continue there?

Additionally, using so many while true loops and relying on break and continue isn't really best practice idt.  I would use do something like use A as input at the very top and your conditions could be something like `while A not in ["RNA", "DNA", PROTEIN"] or something like that and that way it'll keep looping and asking for input until correct one is passed

finally, I would cast every input to be uppercase or lowercase (and your conditional checks too ) that way you can avoid input errors based on case issues